# How to display lines in a file where it contains more than 5 comma in a line using egrep or awk

Tags: perl, shell, awk, grep

I have the lines in the following format:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Btwi.png)

Help is required to display the line alone containing more than 5 comma in a line in a separate file.

Comment: Please post relevant example input and output in text format. Posting your tries (and errors) also makes your question better!

Comment: Hello. Please see [ask] for what makes a good question. Specifically - linking to transient offsite images as the basis for you question doesn't make it helpful for future users of the site. It is also generally a good idea to attempt to solve the problem yourself, and then be specific about where you're having problems.

Answer (score 1):

perl has a `tr` (translate) operator that returns the number of translations that occurred. We can use this to count substrings in a string.

`cat file.txt | perl -ne 'print if tr/,// > 5'`

Comment: or, if you like golf, `perl -ne 'print if tr/,// > 5' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Using egrep:

```
egrep '([^,]*,){6,}'
```

Using awk:

```
awk -F, 'NF>5{print}'
```

Using a sed which has an "extended regular expression option" (I'll assume -r here, but it could be -E):

```
sed -n -r -e '/([^,]*,){6,}/p'
```

Of course you have to be careful what you ask for. For example, if you have a CSV file with commas embedded within "values", and if you only want lines with more than five "values", then things get a little trickier for tools that are not CSV-aware.

Answer (score 0):

Text in image looks like CSV.
then, using AWK...

```
awk -F'","' 'NF>5{print}'
```

like peak's above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have answers to your raw question here.  However, if what you're really asking is if you want to find how many rows have CSV **fields** that exceed 5, then I think you need something like Perl's `Text::CSV` module.

An example of this is the following string:

```
one,two,three,four,five,"six,seven"
```

This has six commas but only five fields.  Do you want to see this line, or do you want to skip it?  If you want to see it (as an exception -- a line with more than five commas), then use one of the methods already suggested.

If you don't, then you really want a CSV parser, and Perl's is quite nice -- more lightweight and easier than most languages, in my opinion:

```
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } );

open my $IN, "<:encoding(utf8)", "file.csv" or die;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($IN)) {
  if (@$row > 5) {
    $csv->combine(@$row);
    print $csv->string(), "\n";
  }
}
close $IN;
```